# Jquery input mask set starting input point after prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-inputmask

Hello Im using the [jquery **input mask**](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask), and I'm stucked.

I have a pattern for phone number (+420 XXX XXX XXX) where X are digits.

This is my current code

```
 phoneInputs.inputmask("+999 999 999 999", {
        "placeholder": "+420 ___ ___ ___",
        "onincomplete": function(){
            $(this).addClass("incomplete");
        },
        "oncomplete": function(){
            $(this).removeClass("incomplete");
        }
    });
```

Everything works fine but the problem is when I start typing into the input I rewrite the +420 number.

I would like to start writing on the index of first normal phone number (not the +420 part). Is it possible somehow? Using this inputmask or jQuery?
Thank you

Comment: `phoneInputs.on('focus click', function(e) {var v = $(this).val(); if(!v){$(this).val("+420");} });`

Comment: It doesnt work. When I start typing, the 420 is append to the end. When i write 123 the result is 123 420.

Comment: Clearly define "first normal phone number" as to me none of that is a valid phone number for my local, thus we need clarity.

Comment: The phone number in my country is +420 XXX XXX XXX. Where X are digits 0-9

Answer (score 1):

One tricky solution, is to use two separate inputs one `disabled` input for the prefix and the second one is for the dynamic phone number, along with some CSS styling to get the style as it was only one field:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="prefix" value="+420" disabled/>
<input type="text" id="phoneInput" />
```

**JS:**

```
let phoneInputs = $("#phoneInput");
phoneInputs.inputmask(" 999 999 999", {
  "placeholder": " ___ ___ ___",
  "onincomplete": function() {
    $(this).addClass("incomplete");
  },
  "oncomplete": function() {
    $(this).removeClass("incomplete");
  }
});
```

**Note:**

- You need to update the inputmask placeholder to `" ___ ___   ___"`, so it doesn't consider the `+420` part.
- And to take the full input value you just need to combine the two
  inputs values.

**Demo:**

This is a working demo:

```js
let phoneInputs = $("#phoneInput");
phoneInputs.inputmask(" 999 999 999", {
  "placeholder": " ___ ___ ___",
  "onincomplete": function() {
    $(this).addClass("incomplete");
  },
  "oncomplete": function() {
    $(this).removeClass("incomplete");
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="text"]#prefix {
  -webkit-appearance: none!important;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align: right;
  width: 35px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-right: 0px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -7px;
  background: white;
}

input[type="text"]#phoneInput {
  -webkit-appearance: none!important;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-left: -4px;
  border-left: 0px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-jQuery-Input-Mask-Plugin-inputmask/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<label>Phone number:</label>
<input type="text" id="prefix" value="+420" disabled/>
<input type="text" id="phoneInput" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include your prefix in the mask definition, taking care to escape any reserved characters.

```
phoneInputs.inputmask("\\+420 999 999 999", { "escapeChar": "\\" });
```

Comment: I would have to confirm this but with this only the "+" will be escaped. Try `phoneInputs.inputmask("\\+\\4\\2\\0 999 999 999")` if you also need the "420" prefixed also